# Report Definition Field Proper Case

Tags: expression, rdlc, strconv

i'm working on a rdlc file, for a report. I need the value of a field to be on ProperCase, however the syntax seems to be wrong.

Using the formula StrConv...[image: StrConv]

Using the formula ProperCase, it's not even recognized...[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax, for anyone that has the same problem
[image: Proper Case Expression]